# hyper v server 2012 r2 delegate vm access

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

How can I grant full access (turn on/off, change VM settings) to only several virtual machines on hyper v server 2012 r2 without using SCVMM? So that other VMs will be invisible to that user

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You need to have some portal between your users and your host if you want this sort of functionality.  SCVMM is only one example of such a portal.